# How to normalize Python string encodings

Tags: python, url, unicode, python-2.x

I have a text file with strings. These strings ultimately represent URL paths (not full URLs), but have been encoded in several ways. Here is an excerpt of the file:

```
25_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D3%99%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0
2_\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0\xD1\x88\xD3\x99\xD0\xB0\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0
5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D3%99%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0
\xD0\x90\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB0
\xD0\x90\xD1\x88\xD3\x99\xD0\xB0\xD1\x85\xD1\x8C\xD0\xB0
function.fopen
Бразилиа
Валерии_Маиромиан
Rome,_Italy
Rome%2C_Italy
```

I would like to guarantee a common format for all these strings, as after loading the file I will need to do string comparisons (e.g. `Rome%2C_Italy` should equal `Rome,_Italy`).

Some lines are URL encoded, and can be easily `unquoted`:

```
import urllib
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        str = urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())
        print str
```

The output of the previous code is:

```
25_рашәара
2_\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0\xD1\x88\xD3\x99\xD0\xB0\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0
5_рашәара
\xD0\x90\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB0
\xD0\x90\xD1\x88\xD3\x99\xD0\xB0\xD1\x85\xD1\x8C\xD0\xB0
function.fopen
Бразилиа
Валерии_Маиромиан
Rome,_Italy
Rome,_Italy
```

My best attempt is the following code:

```
import urllib
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        str = urllib.unquote(line.rstrip()).encode("utf8")
        print str
```

with the following output:

```
25_рашәара
2_\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0\xD1\x88\xD3\x99\xD0\xB0\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0
5_рашәара
\xD0\x90\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB0
\xD0\x90\xD1\x88\xD3\x99\xD0\xB0\xD1\x85\xD1\x8C\xD0\xB0
function.fopen
Бразилиа
Валерии_Маиромиан
Rome,_Italy
Rome,_Italy
```

It seems to have ignored some lines!

In any case, I believe it would be preferrable to simply URL-encode all these strings (as with line `1`), but the `urllib.quote()` method will not work well on the lines that are already URL-encoded (it will encode `%` again!).

Any help clearing up my confusion is appreciated!

Comment: What is the extension of the file you're reading?

Comment: It's a simple `.txt` file!

Comment: What you're attempting to do doesn't make sense to me since you're destroying the url

Comment: As far as I understand, the strings with `\xD1`-style combinations are also UTF-8 encoded, and I would have expected the `str.encode()` method to convert it.

Comment: Plus how could function.fopen ever look like Rome,_Italy.?

Comment: the string `function.fopen` will not equal `Rome,_Italy`, even after normalizing. That comparison is not a problem. The problem is pairs like `Rome,_Italy`, and `Rome%2C_Italy`. What worries me is other instances of two strings that if encoded the same way would be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a similar approach to Eugene Lisitsky except that it runs on Python 2. There *may* be a neater way to do this in Python 2, but it appears to work correctly on the data in the OP.

BTW, you should tag your question with an appropriate Python version tag when you ask a question relating to Unicode, since Unicode handling in Python 3 is quite different to how it works (or fails to do so :) ) in Python 2.

```
import codecs
import urllib

fname = 'input.txt'

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = urllib.unquote(line)
        if r'\x' in line:
            line = codecs.unicode_escape_decode(line)[0]
            line = line.encode('latin1')

        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        print repr(line), line
```

**output**

```
u'25_\u0440\u0430\u0448\u04d9\u0430\u0440\u0430' 25_рашәара
u'2_\u0440\u0430\u0448\u04d9\u0430\u0440\u0430' 2_рашәара
u'5_\u0440\u0430\u0448\u04d9\u0430\u0440\u0430' 5_рашәара
u'\u0410\u043a\u0430\u0431\u0430' Акаба
u'\u0410\u0448\u04d9\u0430\u0445\u044c\u0430' Ашәахьа
u'function.fopen' function.fopen
u'\u0411\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043b\u0438\u0430' Бразилиа
u'\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0438_\u041c\u0430\u0438\u0440\u043e\u043c\u0438\u0430\u043d' Валерии_Маиромиан
u'Rome,_Italy' Rome,_Italy
u'Rome,_Italy' Rome,_Italy
```

As you can see, I've converted all the strings to Unicode objects. If for some reason you want them as plain Python 2 strings just eliminate the `line = line.decode('utf-8')` line.

Answer (score 0):

You may use codecs.unicode_escape_decode to decode backslash-escaped characters like so:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> s=r"\xD0\x90\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB0"
>>> print(s)
\xD0\x90\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB0
>>> s1=codecs.unicode_escape_decode(s)[0]
>>> print(s1)
ÐÐºÐ°Ð±Ð°
>>> bytes(s1,'latin1').decode('utf-8')
'Акаба'
>>>
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP, since he's using Python 2.